# No Response in IOS while using JSON Webservice with Gateway protection

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, web-services

This Below code is Simple Login App. I use Post request to Pass username and Password to get details. But i get @"" Response from web service.

```
email= emailTextField.text;
password=passwordTextfield.text;

NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&Password=%@",email,password];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:Gateway/api/json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;// = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];

NSError *error;// = [[NSError alloc] init;

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Login response: is %@",str);
```

Comment: Look into [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods for providing authentication.

Comment: which method should i call to pass username and Password credentials ?

Comment: NSLog(@"errot: %@",error);

Comment: This is the error o get The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0xa219390 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://1, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:///api/json/reply/Customer/?, NSUnderlyingError=0x8f3e3c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide authentication credentials to a server use NSURLConnection delegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {

        NSURLCredential *credential;
        credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```